CORS issue when connecting frontend and backend on different domains in production (Hostinger) without VPS
I'm staring to get involve in Software development. I’m working on deploying a web application where the frontend and backend are hosted on different domains. I’m using shared hosting on Hostinger and facing an issue with CORS policy.
Frontend: https://servicios.registroms.com (react)deployed with Vite)
Backend: https://api.registroms.com (Node.js server with Express)
The main issue is that I cannot authenticate from the frontend. I’m getting the following error in the browser console:(Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.registroms.com/auth/adminlogin' from origin 'https://servicios.registroms.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.) when I try to login: (index-BTYFrex6.js:42
POST https://api.registroms.com/auth/adminlogin net::ERR_FAILED)
Console Error
Make POST requests with credentials (cookies for JWT authentication) from the frontend to the backend.
I have configured my backend to allow requests only from my frontend domain (https://servicios.registroms.com).
code used in my index.js:
import cors from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
import { adminRouter } from './Routes/AdminRoute.js';
import { EmpleadoRouter } from './Routes/EmpleadoRoute.js';
import Jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { config } from './config.js';

const app = express();

app.use(cors({
    origin: config.CLIENT_URL,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    credentials: true
}));

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('Public'));

const verificarUsuario = (req, res, next) => {
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    if (token) {
        Jwt.verify(token, config.JWT_SECRET_KEY, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) return res.status(403).json({ Status: false, Error: "Token erróneo" });
            req.id = decoded.id;
            req.role = decoded.role;
            next();
        });
    } else {
        return res.status(401).json({ Status: false, Error: "No autenticado" });
    }
};

app.get('/verificar', verificarUsuario, (req, res) => {
    return res.json({ Status: true, role: req.role, userId: req.id });
});

app.use('/auth', adminRouter);
app.use('/empleado', EmpleadoRouter);

const PORT = config.PORT || 3001;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});






htaccess (frontend):
  




# Habilitar el motor de reescritura
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Configuración del MIME type para archivos JavaScript y JSX
AddType application/javascript .js
AddType application/javascript .jsx

# Asegurar que los módulos ES6 y JSX se sirvan con el tipo correcto
<FilesMatch "\.(js|jsx)$">
  Header set Content-Type "application/javascript"
</FilesMatch>

# No redirigir las solicitudes de la API a index.html para /auth y /empleado
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(auth|empleado) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirigir las solicitudes de la API al backend en api.registroms.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(auth|empleado) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://api.registroms.com/$1 [P,L]

# Redirigir todas las demás solicitudes a index.html excepto para archivos y directorios existentes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

# Asegurar que las conexiones WebSocket funcionen correctamente (si las usas)
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*) wss://api.registroms.com/$1 [P,L]







htaccess (backend): 




# Habilitar el motor de reescritura
RewriteEngine On

# Asegurar que las solicitudes a la API no redirijan erróneamente a index.js
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Bloquear el acceso directo a index.js
<Files "index.js">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Files>

# Procesar únicamente las rutas que coincidan con auth o empleado
RewriteRule ^(auth|empleado)(.*)$ index.js [QSA,L]

# Desactivar la exploración de directorios
Options -Indexes

# Evitar el acceso a archivos sensibles
<FilesMatch "\.(env|json|config|lock|log|sh|inc|bak|sql|swp|dist|phar)$">
    Order Allow,Deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

# Configuración de CORS para permitir solicitudes desde el frontend
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://servicios.registroms.com"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Content-Type, Authorization"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials "true"
    
    # Permitir preflight request (OPTIONS)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
</IfModule>

# Evitar que el contenido del archivo index.js sea mostrado en consola
<Files "index.js">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</Files>


Frontend htaccess:

what is the value of config.CLIENT_URL - the error in the picture s different to the error you described ... are you getting two different errors? please clarify what the error in the picture is for, and what response status it returns

This is the value for config.CLIENT_URL: '''https://servicios.registroms.com'''

Status Code:
403 Forbidden

so, that's your code when Jwt.verify fails

As far as I know, it does not even connecting to the backend to start "verificarusuario" and "/adminlogin". All the credentials, routes, DB queries work without problem

so, if (err) return res.status(403).json({ Status: false, Error: "Token erróneo" }); isn't happening?

That is correct, it is not happening, nor the ''' else {
return res.status(401).json({ Status: false, Error: "No autenticado" });
}'''

OK, so the code you posted code used in my index.js: is not the server code. What is?

It's the one that start wen I run "npm start", this is my backend scripts: '''"scripts": {
"start": "node index.js",
"build": "cd ../CiudadanoMS && npm install && npm run build",
"pm2-start": "pm2 start index.js --name server",
"pm2-stop": "pm2 stop server",
"pm2-restart": "pm2 restart server",
"pm2-delete": "pm2 delete server"
},''' One week ago I install the pm2 to run the backend with Hostinger
